# Artifactory as Post-build Actions in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a Jenkins Job that build my maven project. After it's done it does a "Post-build Action" that deploys the Maven artifacts to Artifactory using the Artifactory plugin.

Now I've converted this job to a Jenkins-pipeline. This looks something like this:

```
        def artifactoryMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        artifactoryMaven.tool = 'maven' 
        artifactoryMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-releases', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshots', server: server
        artifactoryMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-releases', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshots', server: server

        artifactoryMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: goals, buildInfo: buildInfo
```

But I liked the previous approach better, where the build and deployment were separate concerns. Is there an easy way to do this? The 'normal' artifactory needed just one checkbox (Deploy maven artifacts) so I'm hoping for a one-liner. Alternatively, I guess I could use an uploadspec? But I'm hoping to avoid that if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code to your Pipeline script, to determine whether your maven artifacts are deployed to Artifactory or not:

`def deployToArtifactory = false    rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts(deployToArtifactory)`

Comment: Just checking if I understand correctly: This still means I've got to use Artifactory.newMavenBuild() to have artifactory kick off maven, right? I can't say to artifactory: here is a maven project that has been build, go figure out what to deploy and do that?